# Const correctness with temporary instances

Tags: c++

Here is the example of the "scoped lock" idiom with common mistake: no local variable is created, so lock is not in effect. This code compiles flawlessly both with VC++ 2010 and Comeau C++ online:

```
class Mutex
{
public:
    void lock() {}
};

class ScopedLock
{
public:
    ScopedLock() : m_pm(0) {}
    ScopedLock(Mutex& m) : m_pm(&m) { m_pm->lock(); }

private:
    Mutex* m_pm;

private:
    ScopedLock& operator =(const ScopedLock&);
    ScopedLock(const ScopedLock&);
};

class X
{
public:
    void foo() const
    {
        ScopedLock(m_mutex);
    }

private:
    Mutex m_mutex;
};


int main()
{
    X x1;
    x1.foo();
}
```

If default constructor for ScopedLock is commented out, then both compilers give an error:

> error C2512: 'ScopedLock' : no appropriate default constructor available

(When `ScopedLock` used correctly, i.e. local variable is created: `ScopedLock guard(m_mutex);`, then compilation fails as expected. Declaring `m_mutex` as mutable fixes the problem.)

I have two questions:

1. Why `X::foo` compiles? It seems that compiler was able to cast `const Mutex&` to `Mutex&` somehow.
2. What role plays `ScopedLock` default constructor, so the compilation succeeds?

Thanks.

**Update:** I found the answer. It appears that `ScopedLock(m_mutex);` statement creates a local variable `m_mutex` of type `ScopedLock`. Not a temporary. That's why `ScopedLock::ScopedLock` default constructor is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You answered the question yourself.

> It appears that ScopedLock(m_mutex); statement creates a local variable m_mutex of type ScopedLock

The explanation is to be found in the Standard's Section 6.8 Ambiguity Resolution:

> There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving expression-statements and declarations: An expression-statement with a function-style explicit type conversion [5.2.3] as its leftmost subexpression can be indistinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator starts with a (. **In those cases the statement is a declaration**.

The Standard then lists `T(a);` as an example of a statement that is really a declaration. It is equivalent to `T a;`

This is one variation of the infamous C++ "most vexing parse".

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your problem is line 26: `ScopedLock(m_mutex);`

Instead, that should be something like  `ScopedLock a_variable_name(m_mutex);`

When I make that change, I get the expected errors:

```
constCorrectness.cpp: In member function ‘void X::foo() const’:
constCorrectness.cpp:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘ScopedLock::ScopedLock(const Mutex&)’
constCorrectness.cpp:18: note: candidates are: ScopedLock::ScopedLock(const ScopedLock&)
constCorrectness.cpp:11: note:                 ScopedLock::ScopedLock(Mutex&)
constCorrectness.cpp:10: note:                 ScopedLock::ScopedLock()
```

<strike>Perhaps somebody can interpret `ScopedLock(m_mutex)` for us? Does it declare a function or something? Instead of calling a constructor as expected by the questioner?</strike>  **Update:** Striking this out. I think it's just a variable declaration (i.e. the brackets are ignored.)

Comment: Commenting on the question I left at the end of my own answer: I think your line 26 simply declares another variable, local to X::foo, also called `m_mutex`. The brackets are basically ignored. This is why it uses the default constructor.

Comment: @aaron-mcdaid, yes, you're right. Just discovered it myself. Local variable of type `ScopedLock` was created.

Comment: That's good. I'd never heard of this idiom before, so thank you for an interesting question.

Comment: the idiom's name is [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). Automatic locking and unlocking of synchronization objects is very common usage of RAII. The problem I described in the original post happened with our usage of `boost::interprocess::scoped_lock` class. This class provides default constructor, so incorrect usage may go unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the X::foo() method is declared as const - that means that it will not mutate (change) the object.

The ScopedLock() constructor doesn't have a overload that accepts a immutable (const) reference to a Mutex object.

Fixing this requires you declare m_mutex as mutable, or provide an appropriate overloaded ScopedLock() constructor.  I'm thinking the former is preferable.